# jQuery subtracting numbers is creating more decimal place that assigned

Tags: jquery, math

Firstly, I just want to say i'm new to JS/JQUERY so forgive me if my terminology or code is all over the place.

i'm writing this little thingy http://codepen.io/mike-grifin/pen/pjRrBb but if you click the 170.99 box and then keep tapping any of the other boxes the total goes to -34041.979999999996 i dont know why it has so many decimal places when i'm using .toFixed(2);

See JQUERY below:

```
$(window).ready(function(){


function getCash () {
return parseFloat (prompt('How much cash you got?'));
}

var customerName = "Mike";//prompt('What is your name?');
var cash = (500).toFixed(2); //getCash().toFixed(2);
while (isNaN(cash)) {
cash = getCash();
}

$('.customer-name').append(customerName);
$('.cash').append(cash);

if (cash <= 0 ) {
$('.result').append("Not enough cash bro!");
}
else if (cash > 1000) {
$('.result').append("woah! Big Spender, Maybe this shop isn't for you.");
 }

else {
$('.result').append("Welcome, shop til you drop");
setTimeout(function(){
$('.shop').removeClass('is-not-showing');
}, 1000);
}

$('.item').on('click', function(){
var purchase = ($(this).text());
$('.cash').text(cash -= purchase).toFixed(2);

});

});
```

Thank you in advance if you can help out at all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first convert the amount then write.

change :

```
$('.cash').text(cash -= purchase).toFixed(2);
```

to:

```
$('.cash').text((cash -= purchase).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Seems to have worked perfectly! thank you. How come the other was was adding so many decimal places? Thanks again!

Comment: @ironmike. Because you tried to apply toFixed to the jQuery object, not the value.